# Yeast Problems!

Tags: fermentation, yeast, repitch

Brewing a porter, pitched my yeast and started with a 1.056. My air conditioner broke for 1 day and the beer got to about 80 degrees after about 1 1/2 weeks of fermentation.  Beer has been sitting at 1.036 for two weeks now. Can I repitch? Or is it needing to be dumped? And if I can repitch, does it need to be transferred to a new bucket first?

Comment: What kind of yeast did  you use? Did you make a starter?

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to dump a beer that isn't contaminated. After 1.5 weeks and a trip to 80F, the beer should be done fermenting. And warm temps late in fermentation have little impact on flavor.

You can try stirring up the yeast, but a re-pitch of active yeast is probably worth doing. If you can make a starter that would really help, since the partly fermented beer contains no oxygen.

Transferring is unnecessary, and risky with the residual sugar still present.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what the gravity reads, that beer is done.  What was the OG?  Was it an extract batch?  I doubt repitching will make any difference.

Comment: So, 1.036 is too high of finishing gravity for just about any style, right? I'd think it would be undrinkable with so much sugar/starch/whatever.

Comment: It wouldn't be too high if you starter at 1.100.  But it is too high from 1.056.  The questions is "why?".  I'd guess you have a highly unfermentable wort, but we'll need to see the recipe and your procedure to know for sure.  But if it hasn't changed in 2 weeks, it's highly unlikely that it will change with more yeast.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by just swirling the carboy so that the yeast bed breaks up. Leave it for a few days and take another reading. It there is no or little change, then do as Pepi says; make a starter and re-pitch to the same fermenter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pop the lid to let in some air, then reattach the lid and give fermenter a good shake, to stir things up, wait a day to see if it kicks off again, if not as pepi suggests use a starter.